# How to use nginx as reverse proxy send all requests to varnish

Tags: nginx, redirect, varnish, 301-redirect, centos8

I have a centos 8
and varnish is on port 80 connecting with apache on port 8080

bellow is my nginx config.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen *:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name site.com;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/privkey.pem;
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
    }

}
```

I believe the 443 requests are ok now.
But what about the non ssl requests ? i want to do the same with the nonssl requests or how to do ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I can come up with 3 possible solutions:

1. Don't worry about plain HTTP on port `80` and just let Varnish handle it
2. Create a vhost for plain HTTP

   - Configure Varnish to listen on port `6081`
   - Copy the `server` block from your Nginx configuration
   - Adjust the block to make sure it listens on port `80`
   - Remove the SSL bits from the duplicated `server` block
   - Make sure your proxy all requests to port `6081`
3. Create a redirection vhost for plain HTTP

   - Configure Varnish to listen on port `6081`
   - Create a `server` block that redirects all HTTP requests to the HTTPS equivalent